# How to write hbar symbol in xmgrace

Tags: xmgrace

The "hbar" is most common symbol used in most physics problems. Xmgrace doesn't include hbar in its symbols library.
How can I write hbar symbol in xmgrace plotting software.

Answer (score 0):

You can use do it by hand using [xmgrace's typesetting capabilities](https://plasma-gate.weizmann.ac.il/Grace/doc/UsersGuide.html#toc7.1). For instance, with the font family and size I'm using `h\h{-0.57}\v{0.32}-` will produce the following hbar:
[image]

Essentially I have shifted `-` horizontally by `-0.57` and vertically by `0.32`. Note that if you want to write something after it you'll have to reset the baseline vertical shift by using `\v{}`